# How to configure SAML 2.0 for Zendesk using Okta?

Tags: single-sign-on, saml-2.0, okta, zendesk

I am using Okta as Identity Provider and Zendesk as Service Provider. I have configured SAML 2.0 as shown in Okta documentation ([link](http://saml-doc.okta.com/SAML_Docs/How-to-Configure-SAML-2.0-for-Zendesk.html?baseAdminUrl=https://dev-817806-admin.oktapreview.com&app=zendesk&instanceId=0oac9rfphgVYOgIWT0h7))

When I click on the Zendesk App from my Okta dashboard, it tries to sign into
Zendesk and then automatically redirect back to Okta homepage.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I was able to resolve the problem by going back into the application sign on configuration and copy the certificate fingerprint and update the zendesk configuration. The fingerprints were different between my initial configuration and troubleshooting. The second attempt worked correctly.